# Mostrar datos de tabla relacionada en laravel

Tags: laravel

Buen dia para todos. Voy al grano de una vez...
Tengo un buscador en mi pequeña app de laravel pero necesito que al escribir un nombre de un usuario, me muestre los posts creados por el. Lo que tengo en este momento es que si escribo una palabra del titulo o del contenido del post si me los muestra, pero no cuando escribo el usuario.

Tabla usuario(campos: id, name, email, password)

Tabla posts(campos: id, user_id, title, body)

Estas son las relaciones que tengo en los modelos:

Modelo User:

```
    public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Modelo Post:

```
    public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'cat_id');
}

    public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Y en el controlador el codigo es:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $searches = $request->input('search');

    $user_posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$searches.'%')
    ->orWhereHas('user', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('user_id', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%");
    })
    ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%'.$searches.'%')->paginate(6);


    return view('admin.search.searches', compact('user_posts'));
}
```

Alguien podria ayudarme por favor... :(

Comment: es que estas filtrando el usuario por la id y no por el nombre. cambia `$query->where('user_id', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%");` por `$query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%");`

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice porloscerros, pero tambien procuraria hacer una consulta independiente por tabla y clasificarlas para mejor usabilidad